# How to add a new .ui to project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm using **Qt 6.4** on **Visual Studio 2022**, I'm trying to understand how to add a new `.ui` to an existing project.

For example, I have a project with a `mainwindow.ui`, when I open it on `Qt Designer` and create a **new** .ui window from:

```
[Qt Designer] File -> New -> Main Window -> Create
```

I added some widgets to this new window and saved it to disk with the name `new_window.ui`.

How do I include it in my current project? I tried `#include "new_window.ui"` but It throws a lot of compiler syntax errors.

What I'm trying to achieve is access the widgets from `new_window.ui` inside of my `MainWindow` class:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    // access the 'ui' from new_window.ui here
    // new_window_ui.pushButton-> ...
}
```

I have seen that this `ui` generally is a **private** class member, there's no problem in having the `new_window.ui` ui public.

What is the correct way to achieve it?

Comment: ***What is the correct way to achieve it?*** Using `ui.setupUi(this);` is one way.

Comment: ***#include "new_window.ui"*** You don't do that.  Your build system will execute `uic` to generate a header for the .ui file. Then you include the generated header in your header for your widget. For me I use CMake for all of my projects so that is what has support to spawn `uic` when needed.

Comment: @drescherjm What generated header? i only have the `new_window.ui`, how do i generate this header you're talking about?

Comment: It depends on what method you are using to run `uic.exe` with a `CMake` based project in Visual Studio I can enable [AUTOUIC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/AUTOUIC.html#prop_tgt:AUTOUIC) and CMake handles running `uic.exe` as a build task in my Visual Studio solution.

Comment: This project is a simple Hello World showing CMake usage with Qt5: [https://github.com/jasondegraw/Qt-CMake-HelloWorld](https://github.com/jasondegraw/Qt-CMake-HelloWorld)

Answer (score -1):

I have been able to include the new `ui` file by creating it on a **new** project and copying the generated `ui_new_window.h` file plus her class header:

```
// new_window.h
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ui_new_window.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class new_windowClass; };
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class new_window : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    new_window(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::new_windowClass())
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
    }

    ~new_window() { delete ui; };

    Ui::new_windowClass *ui;
};
```